# Enabling/disabling Http Service

Tags: spring, http

I have an application which talks to other application for document commit, i have a requirement to enable/disable these http services from admin console whenever the second application is down. I am using Spring and Angualrar. Please suggest a pattern to implement this requirement.

Comment: Store some "service-enabled" flag in your database, and if this flag is false, send back an error from this service instead of proceeding?

Comment: We dont have control on the external service